# Kolmogorov's Maximal Inequality Applied to Difference in Partial Sums

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

As part of an assignment, I am trying to prove a result using Kolmogorov's maximal inequality (for reference, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_inequality)). I believe that I am quite close, however I am unable to justify what appears to be applying Kolmogorov's result over $\{M, \ldots, N\}$ for $N>M\geq1$ instead of the usual $\{1, \ldots, N\}$.

Being more specific let $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be independent random variables with zero mean and finite variances and define $S_n := X_1 + \ldots + X_n$, to be the $n$-th partial sum. For $\epsilon > 0$, I would like to show

$$P\left(\max_{M \leq n \leq N} |S_n - S_M| > \epsilon\right) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\sum_{i=M+1}^{N} \textrm{Var}(X_i).$$

**My approach** so far has been to try and re-index the difference of partial sums on the LHS, so that it looks like 
$$\max_{1 \leq n-M+1 \leq N-M+1} \left| \sum_{i=M+1}^{n} X_{i} \right| = \max_{1 \leq n-M+1 \leq N-M+1} \left| \sum_{i=1}^{n-M} X_{M+i} \right|.$$

At which point if we define $k:=n-M+1$, it follows that

$$\max_{1 \leq n-M+1 \leq N-M+1} \left| \sum_{i=M+1}^{n} X_{i} \right| = \max_{1 \leq k \leq N-M+1} \left| \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} X_{M+i} \right|.$$

Finally, defining $Z_i := X_{i+M}$, I get that

$$\max_{1 \leq n-M+1 \leq N-M+1} \left| \sum_{i=M+1}^{n} X_{i} \right| = \max_{1 \leq k \leq N-M+1} \left| \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} Z_i \right|.$$

The RHS in the last equation is very close to being able to apply Kolmogorov's inequality, but I can't quite massage it to be of the form specified in the inequality theorem. I would appreciate any hints or pushes in the correct direction, preferably without reference to martingale theory since we have not yet covered them in my class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X'_i:=0$ for $i\leqslant M$ and $X'_i=X_i$ for $i\geqslant M+1$ and $S'_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX'_i$. Then $S'_n=S_n-S_M$ for $n\geqslant M$ and $S'_n=0$ for $n\leqslant M$ hence 
$$
\max_{M \leqslant n \leqslant N} |S_n - S_M|=\max_{1\leqslant n\leqslant N}\lvert S'_n\rvert.
$$
Since $\left(X'_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ is independent, Kolmogorov's maximal inequality applies.

Comment: Very elegant solution, thank you!